# Replace template text with given vector of strings in R

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a .txt file which contains an invitation template, where certain values have to be replaced by strings in a given vector.

The text looks like this:

Dear   ,''''we are happy to invite you to our annual showroom . The event starts on  at  in , .''We look forward to your visist.'

Now I need to write a function with the template text and the vector which replaces these placeholders with given values and return the new invitation. the result should look like this

```
Dear Mr. George Clooney , we are happy to invite you to our annual showroom 2022. The event starts on 01.04 at 10.00h in Headquarter Office, Mainroad 26, 4711 Ytown.
```

As of now i opened the textfile and initiated the function and declared. The head of the function looks like this:

```
createLetter <- function(fieldsdata, templateText){
    x <- c(fieldsdata)
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the template text? or does it have to stay like that to start?

Comment: the template text can be transformed in a single character string, which I did, but the replacementpatterns e.g. <TITILE> <FIRSTNAME> <LASTNAME> etc. need to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your placeholder is e.g. "*X*" this is one approach

##### Data

```
st_0 <- c("Dear X , we are happy to invite you to our annual showroom X . The event starts on X at X in X . We look forward to your visit.")
repl <- c("Mr. George Clooney", "2022", "01.04", "10.00h", "Headquarter Office, Mainroad 26, 4711 Ytown")
```

##### Function

Split string into words, get locations of placeholder and replace with fields. Finally join words back together (and remove spaces before <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> with `gsub`).

```
insert <- function(text, fields){
  st <- strsplit(text, " ")[[1]]
  st[st == "X"] <- fields
  gsub(" ([,\\.])", "\\1", paste(st, collapse=" "))
}
```

Use function

```
insert(st_0, repl)
[1] "Dear Mr. George Clooney, we are happy to invite you to our annual showroom 2022. The event starts on 01.04 at 10.00h in Headquarter Office, Mainroad 26, 4711 Ytown. We look forward to your visit."
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial thinking is that you want to leverage `glue` here:

```r
template <- "Dear {title} {name}, we are happy to invite you to our annual showroom {year}. The event starts on {date} at {time} in {location}. We look forward to your visist."

createLetter <- function(templateText, ...){
    glue::glue(templateText, ...)
}

createLetter(template, 
             title = "Mr.", 
             name = "George Clooney",
             year = "2022",
             date = "01.04",
             time = "10.00h",
             location = "Headquarter Office, Mainroad 26, 4711 Ytown")
#> Dear Mr. George Clooney, we are happy to invite you to our annual showroom 2022. The event starts on 01.04 at 10.00h in Headquarter Office, Mainroad 26, 4711 Ytown. We look forward to your visist.
```

Comment: the data (title, name, etc.) needs to be a pre defined vector and in the function in the parameter. The pattern of the templatestring is: <Title>, <Name>.